# SQL query for displaying record with maximum number of non-empty fields

Tags: sql

I am looking for a query/set of SQL queries that will give me the record ID of the record which has the "maximum number of non-empty/non-null fields".
I was looking into `count()` and `max()` functions, but they seem to be solving problems for the same column, but not for the same row (which is what I am looking for).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `order by` the amount of non-empty fields:

```
select  top 1 Record_ID
from    YourTable
order by
        case when isnull(col1,'') <> '' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when isnull(col2,'') <> '' then 1 else 0 end +
        case when isnull(col3,'') <> '' then 1 else 0 end +
        ...
        case when isnull(colN,'') <> '' then 1 else 0 end
```

This is SQL Server syntax.  If you're using another database, please amend your question.

Comment: Thanks Andomar, and your response was bang on target. Just that since I was using a sqllite DB, I had to change isnull to ifnull() and top 1 to LIMIT 1. However, if I had to do this among different DBs, then I am wondering if I could store the value of number of non-empty fields, so I can compare them and choose the winner. How about that Andomar?

Comment: I figured out a workaround..Using the UNION keyword, I plug in all required records into the same (temporary) table, and then perform this query. I add a constant field to determine which DB the winner comes from (same record ID may be prevalent in both DBs, so this is required). Using these two, I figure out the winner. Thanks a ton for the help guys.